# Mongodb. How to get boolean value representing existance of id in an array of ids?

Tags: node.js, api, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a model which have property

```
_idUserReadArr //  array of users who have read an article
```

It is going to be a huge array.

And I want my API to return a boolean value

```
isRead
```

Which should be true if `_idUserReadArr` contains particular id and false in other case.

So, instead of

```
_idUserArr = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to get `isRead = true` or `isRead = false` and do NOT return or do some manipulations directly with big `_idUserReadArr` array.

I'n working with node.js using mongoose.

Comment: You can use a query such as `model.find({_id: articleId, _idUserReadArr: myUserId}, {_id: true}).count().exec(function(err, num) {})` and `num` is a `truthy/falsey` value (0 if not found, 1 if found). Does this help, or did I misunderstand your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Without using the aggregation framework, you can't change the nature of the output, but with a simple wrapper, you can come very close. In this case, using the aggregation framework really isn't necessary as this solution is simple and efficient.

When you specify the `find` that you need, just limit the results to a single field (like `_id`).

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

```
myModel.find({ ... condition ... }, "_id", function(err, docs) {
   // the existence of the doc means your condition was true
   // without sending back the entire document/array structure
});
```

`findOne` also has the same [functionality](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) (as do several of the other `findXYZ` functions in Mongoose).

This functionality is supported by MongoDB's native support for a projection as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking in that direction but it won't be efficient if I want to get information about 100 items from db. Some of them might be read by concrete user and some of them - may be not. Also there are some are fields except _idUserReadArr so I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: What do you mean, a "general" solution? You can exclude fields with a `-fieldname` instead. I think you're looking for something that doesn't exist in MongoDB efficiently.